# Setup Windows 7 and Ubuntu on same hard drive

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Which one to setup first and how to partition the disk to have Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot? Which one is better to boot load? Any guide in details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past it has always been wise to install windows first and linux second since windows has a history trashing any boot loaders it finds. In addition most linux installers have very good tools for partitioning your HDD and setting up boot loaders.

As to partitioning it's entirely up to you. We can't guess how much space you need for your linux or win7. But a I would do the following

- A partition `C:`for the windows install (minimum 80GB)
- A partition for linux install (minimum 50GB)
- One or more data partitions readable from both win and linux for video, music whatever

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Nifle's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/177786/setup-windows-7-and-ubuntu-on-same-hard-drive/177788#177788).

Windows first and make sure you use as few partitions as possible for Windows.  Get the O/S installed and then just leave it until you have linux up and running.

I've never bothered with a separate partition that can be read by both OSs but it sounds a reasonable idea if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Some resources below to make your life easier:

1) [Dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu - dedoimedo.com](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html)

2) [Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu in Perfect Harmony - lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony)

These ought help you through the install process, and these guides require that you install Widows 7 first.

---

Here's a [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999) with Ubuntu installed first, be warned that I have not personally tested this